# Adding "example" Tag to Protobuf-generated Structures for Documentation

Tags: go, swagger, tags, protocol-buffers

I'm facing an issue with adding example tags to structures generated from protobuf in Go, specifically for documentation with Swaggo (https://github.com/swaggo/swag). In JSON, I can easily include an "example" tag to provide examples for documentation purposes. For instance:

```golang
type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name" example:"John"`
}
```

However, when it comes to protobuf-generated structures, like the one below:

```golang
type User struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Name string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=name,proto3" json:"name,omitempty"`
}
```

I can't find a straightforward way to include an "example" tag, especially for use with Swaggo when documenting APIs and showcasing examples of request payloads.

Is there a recommended approach or workaround for adding example tags to protobuf-generated structures in Go, particularly when using Swaggo for documentation? I appreciate any insights or best practices to address this issue.

Thank you!

I explored the Swaggo documentation and searched through online forums for any specific guidelines or extensions that would allow me to include example tags for protobuf-generated structures. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a direct solution.

Comment: Did you have a look at https://github.com/srikrsna/protoc-gen-gotag?